# How do we get the number of create/update/rollback records in a ActiveRecord transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, transactions, rails-activerecord

In a ActiveRecord transaction block, how do I get to know the number of records that were created/updated/rollbacked? for specific model.

This information is needed to know the history of what happened during the transaction job and report to the user.

Comment: do you need to for a single table?

Comment: try audited gem: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Comment: or even: https://github.com/gouravtiwari/audit_rails

Comment: while both of those gems are extremely interesting they both come with the cost of additional database overhead--meaning they have migrations. Having said that, I couldn't find anything on the Rails ActiveRecord apis that seemed to support what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction either succeeds entirely, or fails and the database is rolled back to the state before the transaction.

There is no notion of partial completion for a transaction.

Comment: If it succeeds only I need the report of those actions(create/update) happened within that transaction.